# Как вставить текст в textview из адаптера

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

**Дано:** адаптер и фрагмент

**Нужно** обратиться из адаптера к textview который находится во фрагменте и вставить туда текст.

**Как это можно реализовать?**

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout;
 import com.daimajia.swipe.adapters.RecyclerSwipeAdapter;

 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.text.ParseException;
 import java.util.List;

 import ru.by_em.my_finances.BaseActivity;
 import ru.by_em.my_finances.Category;
 import ru.by_em.my_finances.CategoryList;
 import ru.by_em.my_finances.R;
 import ru.by_em.my_finances.ShowItemActivity;
 import ru.by_em.my_finances.db.DBDataSource;
 import ru.by_em.my_finances.db.DBHelper;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 21.10.2016.
 */

public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<CategoryList> studentList;
private View fragmentView;
private DBHelper dbHelper;
private DBDataSource myDb;
boolean type;   //true income   //false costs

private TextView myMoney;
private TextView sum_today;
private TextView sum_yesterday;
private RecyclerView todayList;
private TextView todayEmptyView;
private RecyclerView yesterdayList;
private TextView yesterdayEmptyView;

public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryList> objects, boolean type, View fragmentView) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.studentList = objects;
    this.type = type;
    this.fragmentView = fragmentView;
}

@Override
public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.swipe_row_item, parent, false);
    myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    initFragmentView();

    final CategoryList item = studentList.get(position);

    viewHolder.categoryName.setText((item.getName()) /*+ "  -  Row Pos. " + position*/);
    viewHolder.categoryPhoto.setImageResource(item.getPhotoId());
    viewHolder.itemSum.setText(item.getSum());
    viewHolder.itemDate.setText(item.getDate());
    viewHolder.moneyType.setText(item.getMoneyType());

    viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);

    // Drag From Left
    //viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper1));

    // Drag From Right
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));

    // Handling different events when swiping
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
            //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
            //you are swiping.
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
            //when the BottomView totally show.
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
            //when user's hand released.
        }
    });

    /*viewHolder.swipeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ((((SwipeLayout) v).getOpenStatus() == SwipeLayout.Status.Close)) {
                //Start your activity

                Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName() + " \n" + item.getEmailId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });*/

    viewHolder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName() + " \n" + item.getMoneyType(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), ShowItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            //Log.d(BaseActivity.LOG_TAG, "sebtype = " + type);

            myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext);
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);

            try {
                intent.putExtra("idOfTransaction", myDb.getIdOfTransaction(item.getdateToDeleteItem()));
                //Log.d(BaseActivity.LOG_TAG, "sebDidOfTransaction = " + myDb.getIdOfTransaction(item.getdateToDeleteItem()));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dbHelper.close();

            intent.putExtra("categoryName", viewHolder.categoryName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("itemSum", viewHolder.itemSum.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("itemDate", viewHolder.itemDate.getText().toString());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    viewHolder.btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked on Map " + viewHolder.categoryName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    viewHolder.tvShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Share " + viewHolder.categoryName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.tvEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Edit  " + viewHolder.categoryName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
            studentList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, studentList.size());
            mItemManger.closeAllItems();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "+" + viewHolder.itemSum.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext);
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);

            try {
                if (type) {
                    myDb.deleteTask(myDb.getIdOfTransaction(item.getdateToDeleteItem()), true);
                } else {
                    myDb.deleteTask(myDb.getIdOfTransaction(item.getdateToDeleteItem()), false);
                }
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG,"item.getDate() = " + DBDataSource.makeDate2(item.getDate(), true));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dbHelper.close();
//тут изменяю данные в textview
            if (fragmentView != null) {

                //myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext.getApplicationContext());

                try {

                    hide_or_show_todayList();
                    hide_or_show_yesterdayList();

                    if (type) {
                        myMoney.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.myMoney) + " " + String.valueOf(myDb.getMyMoney()));
                        sum_today.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.income_today) + " " + String.valueOf(myDb.getSum(true, true)));
                        sum_yesterday.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.income_yesterday) + " " + String.valueOf(myDb.getSum(false, true)));
                    } else {
                        myMoney.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.myMoney) + " " + String.valueOf(myDb.getMyMoney()));
                        sum_today.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.costs_today) + " " + String.valueOf(myDb.getSum(true, false)));
                        sum_yesterday.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.costs_yesterday) + " " + String.valueOf(myDb.getSum(false, false)));
                    }
                } catch (SQLException | ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    // mItemManger is member in RecyclerSwipeAdapter Class
    mItemManger.bindView(viewHolder.itemView, position);

}

private void initFragmentView() {
    if (fragmentView != null) {
        myMoney = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView_myMoney);
        sum_today = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sum_today);
        sum_yesterday = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sum_yestarday);

        todayList = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        todayEmptyView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view_today);
        yesterdayList = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rvList2);
        yesterdayEmptyView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view_yesterday);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return studentList.size();
}

@Override
public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
    return R.id.swipe;
}

public void add(Category category, TextView textView_sum, Boolean type) throws SQLException, ParseException {
    myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext);
    myDb.add(category, textView_sum, false);
//        hide_or_show_todayList();
        //hide_or_show_yesterdayList();
}

public void updateList(List<CategoryList> newlist) throws SQLException, ParseException {
    studentList.clear();
    studentList.addAll(newlist);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
   // hide_or_show_todayList();
    //hide_or_show_yesterdayList();
}

public void hide_or_show_todayList() throws SQLException, ParseException {
    //true income
    //false costs
    myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext);
    if (myDb.getTodayItems(true).size() == 0) {
        todayList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        todayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        todayList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        todayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (myDb.getTodayItems(false).size() == 0) {
        todayList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        todayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        todayList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        todayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void hide_or_show_yesterdayList() throws SQLException, ParseException {
    //true income
    //false costs
    myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext);
    if (myDb.getYesterdayItems(true).isEmpty()) {
        yesterdayList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        yesterdayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        yesterdayList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yesterdayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (myDb.getYesterdayItems(false).isEmpty()) {
        yesterdayList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        yesterdayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        yesterdayList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yesterdayEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
//  ViewHolder Class

public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
    TextView tvDelete;
    TextView tvEdit;
    TextView tvShare;
    ImageButton btnLocation;

    TextView categoryName;
    TextView itemSum;
    TextView itemDate;
    TextView moneyType;
    ImageView categoryPhoto;

    public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        tvDelete = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete);
        tvEdit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);
        tvShare = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvShare);
        btnLocation = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);

        categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        categoryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_photo);
        itemSum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_sum);
        itemDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
        moneyType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.moneyType);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Сначала уточнение. Задача адаптера - формировать однотипные вью для списка. Вам же нужно обращаться к какому-то textview "во фрагменте". Скорее всего, это должно случиться в ответ на какое-то действие пользователя. Так это или нет? Если нет, то описывайте подробнее.

Comment: @tse, есть список операций при удалении должно обновиться значение textview во фрагменте

Comment: @java, под операциями понимается к-л действие, происходящее по нажатию?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, при нажатии кнопки удалить происходит удаление операции после чего должна обновиться сумма в textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо все разнести по контекстам, чтобы фрагмент выполнял свою задачу, как контроллер, а адаптер отображал данный ему список, а не выполнять всю работу фрагмента внутри себя. Вот что получилось по-быстрому бегло написать(часть кода удалено, чтобы сфокусировать внимание на предмете вопроса):

Adapter:

```
public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {

    private StudentClickListener listener;

    private List<CategoryList> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    private DBDataSource myDb;

    boolean type;   //true income   //false costs



    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, boolean type, StudentClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        myDb = new DBDataSource(context);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        this.studentList = objects;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setModels(List<CategoryList> objects) {
        this.studentList = objects;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.swipe_row_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        final CategoryList item = studentList.get(position);

        viewHolder.categoryName.setText((item.getName()) /*+ "  -  Row Pos. " + position*/);
        viewHolder.categoryPhoto.setImageResource(item.getPhotoId());
        viewHolder.itemSum.setText(item.getSum());
        viewHolder.itemDate.setText(item.getDate());
        viewHolder.moneyType.setText(item.getMoneyType());

        // init swipe item ....
        // init swipe item ....
        // init swipe item ....

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }

    public void add(Category category, TextView textView_sum, Boolean type) throws SQLException, ParseException {
        myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext);
        myDb.add(category, textView_sum, false);
//        hide_or_show_todayList();
        //hide_or_show_yesterdayList();
    }

    public void updateList(List<CategoryList> newlist) throws SQLException, ParseException {
        studentList.clear();
        studentList.addAll(newlist);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // hide_or_show_todayList();
        //hide_or_show_yesterdayList();
    }

    public void hide_or_show_todayList() throws SQLException, ParseException {
       //hide/show logic
    }

    public void hide_or_show_yesterdayList() throws SQLException, ParseException {
        //hide show logic
    }

    public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        TextView tvDelete;
        TextView tvEdit;
        TextView tvShare;
        ImageButton btnLocation;

        TextView categoryName;
        TextView itemSum;
        TextView itemDate;
        TextView moneyType;
        ImageView categoryPhoto;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            tvDelete = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete);
            tvEdit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);
            tvShare = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvShare);
            btnLocation = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
            btnLocation.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvShare.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
            categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            categoryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_photo);
            itemSum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_sum);
            itemDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
            moneyType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.moneyType);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.tvDelete) listener.deleteClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            if (v.getId() == R.id.tvEdit) listener.editCliced(getAdapterPosition());
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLocation) listener.mapClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            if (v.getId() == R.id.tvShare) listener.shareClicked(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


}
```

Fragment:

```
public class SdudentsListFragment extends Fragment {

    private View fragmentView;
    private TextView myMoney;
    private TextView sum_today;
    private TextView sum_yesterday;
    private RecyclerView todayList;
    private TextView todayEmptyView;
    private RecyclerView yesterdayList;
    private TextView yesterdayEmptyView;
    private SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        adapter = new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), true, createClick());
    }

    private SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.StudentClickListener createClick() {
        return new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.StudentClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void mapClicked(int position, CategoryList item) {

            }

            @Override
            public void shareClicked(int position, CategoryList item) {

            }

            @Override
            public void editCliced(int position, CategoryList item) {

            }

            @Override
            public void deleteClicked(int position, CategoryList item) {
                //логика удаления операции над данными и View
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        myMoney = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView_myMoney);
        sum_today = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sum_today);
        sum_yesterday = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sum_yestarday);

        todayList = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        todayEmptyView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view_today);
        yesterdayList = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rvList2);
        yesterdayEmptyView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view_yesterday);

        //setup recycler view
        //adapter.setModels();
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface StudentClickListener {

            void mapClicked(int position, CategoryList item);

            void shareClicked(int position, CategoryList item);

            void editCliced(int position, CategoryList item);

            void deleteClicked(int position, CategoryList item);

        }
```

**P.S** Логику работы с Базой данных тоже всю нужно вынести во фрамент в адаптер пихать/обновлять/удалять уже готовые объекты CategoryList, через сигнатуру интерфейса, передавайте те параметры, которые вам нужны

Comment: я так и не смог ваш код добавить, если не сложно не подскажите хоть где можно про адаптеры прочитать и разобраться в инете очень много статей, но все пишут по разному, в голове образовалась каша, которую никак не разгребу(

Comment: @java код, то потому что написаный на коленке у меня же нет ваших объектов, нужно понять в чем смысл, что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: в адаптере на   `this.studentList = objects и if (v.getId() == R.id.tvDelete) listener.deleteClicked(getAdapterPosition());`  во фрагменте не видит интерфейс хоть он создан предлагает создать новый

Comment: А где вы берете список данных?

Comment: если что пользуюсь данной либой https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: список достается из бд

Comment: 2 момент : обратите внимание на `public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener`

Comment: Попробуйте вынести интерфейс в отдельный класс

Comment: Достаньте список из бд во фрагменте и передайте его в адаптер, с помощью метода setModels(), раньше у вас это было в контрукторе адаптера

Comment: на сколько я знаю, это нельзя спрашивать тут, но у вас есть вк? мнеб с адаптерами разобраться

Comment: да тут дело не в адаптере, а скорее в понимании ооп и Android SDK

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52933/discussion-between-java-and-georgehardcore).

Comment: я написал в чат, если можете посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Чуть позже, сейчас не могу

Comment: спасибо, буду ждать

Comment: оповещения приходят долго почему то, вы тут?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением параметров в конструктор

```
    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryList> objects, boolean type, View fragmentView) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.studentList = objects;
    this.type = type;
    this.fragmentView = fragmentView;
}
```

Comment: плохо решили, нужно было повесить callback на удаление и вывести нужные данные в фрагмент с помощью него

Comment: @georgehardcore, а как это?

Comment: Добавьте код адаптера хотя бы частично

Comment: @georgehardcore, добавил, а почему мой вариант плохой?